# How can I get a light pink or purple pale tint to my photos (similar to Instagram user's)?

Tags: photo-editing, effect, apps, instagram

I want my pictures to get a light pink purple pale tint, like this [Instagram user's photos](https://i.instagram.com/miilkiest/). What filter or app is she using to get that look?

Comment: That is not photography related, you ask about a website usage.

Comment: @Olivier- I believe she is asking about how to obtain a Pink/Purple tint to her pictures, similar to the posts on the Instagram Link and not about website usage. this question should remain open as it is photography related and therefore, can be answered on this stack.

Comment: Have you tried asking her directly?

Comment: @abdul N Quraishi yes that's what I ment thank you

Comment: @scottbb yea but she has not answered and she's sort of instagram famous so I don't think she'll reply

Comment: I suspect that while post processing is used to steer pictures towards that effect, that MOST of the result is from the actual scenes. ie most of her props/clothes/... are in fact pink hued. It is possible that masks are used to selectively colour some areas but some of the photos are very complex if this is how it is done. - eg hair over skin. In other photos there are areas or objects which are not pink biased mixed in amongst those that are. If it's done with a program then it has the ability to very accurately pick out edges - it would be far easier tp just have accessories that matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually adjust your white balance or gel your lens or flash.  Otherwise use instagram to modify your photos.